# How do I get command-line Perl to accept shell variables?

Tags: bash, perl

I can do math like

```
perl -e 'print 5253413/39151' -l
```

But I don't quite get how to take advantage of Perl's ability to do math with my own predefined bash variables. I've tried

```
var1=$(some wc command that yields a number); var1=$(some wc that yields another number)
perl -e 'print var1/var2' -l
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that your `var1/var2` is just text to Perl. Even after correcting it to `$var/$var2`, the script can't see that these two variables are defined in the shell calling the script. You must pass their values to the script in some way (e.g. as environment variables, see the answers).

Answer (score 15):

There are two main ways to do this.

- Within the Perl code you can use the `%ENV` built-in hash to access environment variables that are *exported* from the shell

  ```
  $ export var1=5253413
  $ export var2=39151
  $ perl -E 'say $ENV{var1}/$ENV{var2}'
  134.183366963807
  ```
- You can use the shell interpolation facility to insert the value of a shell variable into a command

  This is best done as *parameters* to the perl one-liner rather than introducing the values directly into the code

  ```
  $ var1=5253413
  $ var2=39151
  $ perl -E '($v1, $v2) = @ARGV; say $v1/$v2' $var1 $var2
  134.183366963807
  ```

Comment: +1; also worth mentioning the more concise ad-hoc, one-off method of defining environment variables for a command: `var1=5253413 var2=39151 perl -E 'say $ENV{var1}/$ENV{var2}'`

Comment: @mklement0: I considered including that but dismissed it as being more centred on shell techniques than Perl. But in retrospect I guess that's what this question's all about. I'll leave your comment to represent it. Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, the quickest (and dirtiest) way to do this is just `perl -e 'print '$var1/$var2 -l`

Comment: @reinierpost , I tried that and it didn't work. Why is it considered dirty ?

Comment: @Tom: what do you mean by *it didn't work*? What was the error message? The reason it's dirty is that it will only work if `$var1` and `$var2` have been set to numbers (e.g. they must not contain any whitespace).

Comment: @Tom:  Avinash Raj deleted his own answer - I presume after it had received 2 down-votes (neither of them from me). What gave you the idea that _I_ deleted it (a power I do not possess)? The answer suggested using a _double-quoted_ string as the Perl script, which meant that the _shell_ would have expanded shell variable references before Perl even got to see the script. While that would have worked in this simple case, it gets confusing quickly in cases where both Perl and shell variables are involved. There's also a security risk - see pilcrow's comment on his own answer below.

Comment: @mklement0; My mistake, I have a saved version of the answer so I'll use that. I'm new to stackoverflow, so I figured that since you could edit my post that you did some admin things


@reinierpost, I misread where you put the single quotes, now I see that it works. This is really useful to know. Why does it print the evaluation despite the division operation being outside the single quotes of print?

Comment: @reinierpost, Furthermore, it seems that if I remove the space in front of print, it no longer yields anything. What's going on? Is the single quote actually some sort of escape character that I'm looking at?

Comment: Why not just `perl -E '($v1, $v2) = @ARGV; say $v1/$v2' 5253413 39151` and not bother with the shell variables?

Answer (score 6):

Two less common ways to do this make use of long-standing perl features.

The first is the [core module `Env`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html), which ties process environment variables to perl variables:

```
sh$ export VAR1=1000
sh$ export VAR2=33
sh$ perl -MEnv -E 'say $VAR1/$VAR2'           # imports all environ vars
333.333333333333
sh$ perl -MEnv=VAR1,VAR2 -E 'say $VAR1/$VAR2' # imports only VAR1, VAR2
333.333333333333
```

Note that the variables need to be present in the environment inherited by the perl process, for example with [`export VAR`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_22) as above, or explicitly for a single command (as by `FOO=hello perl -MEnv -E 'say $FOO'`).

The second and rather more obscure way is to use use perl's [`-s` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-s*) to set arbitrary variables from the command line:

```
sh$ VAR1=1000
sh$ VAR2=33
sh$ perl -s -E 'say $dividend/$divisor' -- -dividend=$VAR1 -divisor=$VAR2
333.333333333333
```

awk does something similar with its [`-v` switch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_04).

Comment: Environment variables are also available via the global `%ENV` hash; `shell# export FOO=BAR && perl -E 'say $ENV{FOO}'`

Comment: @Joshua, of course, but many perl hackers and admins in need of a one-liner are just(ly) [too impatient](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris) to type `$ENV{this}` and `$ENV{that}`. :)

Comment: This is a really neat idea and I almost want to vote for it as an answer. But, wouldn't just using double quotes work just fine? For some reason this answer was deleted, but someone said that you could do 
`perl -e "print $var1/$var2" -l`

Comment: @Tom, the danger with simply interpolating the shell variables into the perl command string is twofold.  First, these constructions are confusing to folks who can't get the quoting and variable expansion quite right — is that `"$foo"` a shell var or a perl var? — and quickly become opaque when you've quotes within quotes.  Second, this practice is essentially an _eval_ in your perl program, a code injection opportunity.  If you get too cavalier about that, even in one-liners, you'll hurt yourself one day.

Comment: @pilcrow. I'm not sure I understand your figures of speech. Can expand your explanation to provide more detail? It seems like this solution is identical to the one you provided, just without the export step. It seems much more intuitive just to put it in double quotes

Comment: @Tom, `perl -E "say '$SHELL_VAR'"` is easy.  `perl -E "say qq(\$^V says \x24SHELL_VAR is $SHELL_VAR)"` is trickier.  `export SHELL_VAR="system q(rm -rf /)"` might be devastating.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the spirit of the question is to pass variables without exported ENV vars.

Beside using **perl `-s` -e expression -perlvar=val**, below is code that uses two other mechanisms to pass the variable to perl.

```
a=x; b=N; c=z;
b=y perl -e '$pa='$a';'  -e "\$pc=$c;" -e 'print "$pa$ENV{b}$pc\n";'
echo $a$b$c
```

Passing a and c is same, only the quoting is different. When passing using chained expressions, like this, it is important to end the expression with semi-colon; because, they flow into one expression at the end.

Passing b is done by ENV, but instead of using the exported value, it is passed directly into perl's ENV by giving the assignment before the command on the same command-line.

Last the echo command is to emphasize how the shell's definition of $b is unchanged.

Using the mechanism of b's passing, we arrive at a more secure solution, because the process's ENV data cannot be checked for the value, and it will not be seen in the command-line argument list.