# Attempting to create a script that allows replacing an exact given string in all the files extensions mentioned

Tags: bash

I want a bash script that replaces the exact given input string by user with the exact given string by the user. This includes string that may include special characters. Example: user enters T.O.L, this should only repalce the word "T.O.L" in files, including the dots. Currently my issue is that it looks for a pattern, in this case it's also replacing words that have a pattern like it replaces the word "Total" because the dots in the input string is replaced by the letters "t" and "a" here. I only want it to replace T.O.L and nothing else.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter server: " source_dir

dir_1="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/a1f6-5db916af0069"
dir_2="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/9e98-7067a2fc7724"
dir_3="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/8063-666eb46e7786"
dir_4="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/8b43-2563b7b8f05c"
dir_5="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/aac0-9be3cd157266"
dir_6="/var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/ad2e-d64611637a8d"

if   [ "$source_dir" = "dir_1" ]; then target_dir="$dir_1"
elif [ "$source_dir" = "dir_2" ]; then target_dir="$dir_2"
elif [ "$source_dir" = "dir_3" ]; then target_dir="$dir_3"
elif [ "$source_dir" = "dir_4" ]; then target_dir="$dir_4"
elif [ "$source_dir" = "dir_5" ]; then target_dir="$dir_5"
elif [ "$source_dir" = "dir_6" ]; then target_dir="$dir_6"
else target_dir="$source_dir"
fi

read -p "Enter string to find: " string_old
echo "Looking for: $string_old"
read -p "Enter string to replace with: " string_new
echo "Replacing with : $string_new"

file_ext=("txt" "cfg")

for ext in "${file_ext[@]}"; do
    find "$target_dir" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\Q'"$string_old"'\E/\Q'"$string_new"'\E/g' {} \;
done
```

I managed to get this far, but now facing an issue where it won't replace the string if it has a space after or before and only looks for a string in newline with no spaces before or after. Now i'm stuck at an issue, the replaced string replaces the dot in the input with a slash / \ / \

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using shell string concatenation to substitute the variables, assign them to perl variables as shown in [How do I get command-line Perl to accept shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867063/how-do-i-get-command-line-perl-to-accept-shell-variables)

```
export string_old string_new
for ext in "${file_ext[@]}"; do
    find "$target_dir" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{string_old}\E/\Q$ENV{string_new}\E/g' {} \;
done
```

Comment: I don't know `perl` so idk if there's a reason to only process one file at a time but could the OP use `+` instead of `\;` at the end of the `find` to process multiple files on each call to `perl` for efficiency?

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, you can do that. `perl -pi -e '...'` is similar to `sed -i '...'`, it will process all the files in the argument list and edit them in place.

Answer (score 0):

This is one case where I might actually consider using perl as there's no concise way to do global substitutions with literal strings in sed or awk but anyway, here's how you could do it in any POSIX awk (untested):

```
xfrom() {
    string_old="$string_old" string_new="$string_new" \
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            old = ENVIRON["string_old"]
            new = ENVIRON["string_new"]
            lgth = length(old)
        }
        {
            head = ""
            tail = $0
            while ( s=index(tail,old) ) {
                head = head substr(tail,1,s-1) new
                tail = substr(tail,s+lgth)
            }
            print head tail
        }
    }
}
export -f xform

for ext in "${file_ext[@]}"; do
    find "$target_dir" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec  bash -c 'xform "$@"' bash {} +
done
```